# create a json object containing an array of json object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to get the following json object:

```
{
 "Customers":[
  {
   "name": "Jason",
   "country": "USA"
  }
 ]
}
```

This is my current code :

```
$data = [
    'Customers' => [
      'name' => "Jason",
      'country' => "USA"
  ]
];
```

but it doesn't give me the good result:

```
{"Customers": {"name": "Jason", "country": "USA"}}
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customers contains an array which you were missing

```
$data = [
    'Customers' => [
        ['name' => "Jason", 'country' => "USA"]
  ]
];

print_r(json_encode($data));
```

RESULT

```
{"Customers":[{"name":"Jason","country":"USA"}]}
```